# Sequelize db:migrate throw TypeError: Data must be a string or a buffer

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

```
crypto.js:74
  this._handle.update(data, encoding);
               ^
TypeError: Data must be a string or a buffer
at TypeError (native)
at Hash.update (crypto.js:74:16)
at sha1 (/mnt/projects/Nodejs/develda/node_modules/mysql2/lib/auth_41.js:30:8)
at Object.token [as calculateToken] (/mnt/projects/Nodejs/develda/node_modules/mysql2/lib/auth_41.js:64:16)
at new HandshakeResponse (/mnt/projects/Nodejs/develda/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packets/handshake_response.js:25:24)
at ClientHandshake.sendCredentials (/mnt/projects/Nodejs/develda/node_modules/mysql2/lib/commands/client_handshake.js:46:27)
at ClientHandshake.handshakeInit (/mnt/projects/Nodejs/develda/node_modules/mysql2/lib/commands/client_handshake.js:122:10)
at ClientHandshake.Command.execute (/mnt/projects/Nodejs/develda/node_modules/mysql2/lib/commands/command.js:39:20)
at Connection.handlePacket (/mnt/projects/Nodejs/develda/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:417:28)
at PacketParser.onPacket (/mnt/projects/Nodejs/develda/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:93:16)
at PacketParser.executeStart (/mnt/projects/Nodejs/develda/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packet_parser.js:73:14)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/mnt/projects/Nodejs/develda/node_modules/mysql2 /lib/connection.js:101:29)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
at TCP.onread (net.js:547:20)
```

I'm getting this error when I try to migrate with node_modules/.bin/sequelize db:migrate

I think the mysql2 package causes this error

I'm appreciate for your help

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, please make sure your config.json **does not** contain any unquoted values like the password in this example:

```
{
 "my_env": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": 1234,
    "database": "my_db",
    "host"    : "localhost",
    "dialect" : "mysql"
  }
}
```

If that doesn't solve your problem and you have a strong reason to believe it has something to do with mysql2 package, try downgrading your sequelize package to v3 and which uses mysql rather than mysql2

Comment: god bless u achinu :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use the command "**sequelize init**" to init the project,then you should check your config.json.Because by default "**port**" field don't include.
Meanwhile，please make sure your **config.json** does not contain any unquoted  like the password in this example.

```
{
 "my_env": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": 1234,
    "database": "my_db",
    "host"    : "localhost",
    "dialect" : "mysql"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had an empty object in my database.json file:

```json
{
  "dev": {
    "driver": "pg",
    "user": {"ENV": "DB_USER"},
    "password": {"ENV": "DB_PASS"},
    "host": {"ENV": "DB_HOST"},
    "database": {},              <-- THIS LINE
    "port": {"ENV": "DB_PORT"}
  }
}
```

The line: `"database": {},` was causing the issue.

"database" should be a string.